# Convert backslashes to forward in all files apart from one in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

Have a directory, say \configuration. There are multiple files in it. I am trying to convert the backslashes in the contents of all the files to forward slashes, apart from one file. So, I need to run a loop for the contents of the file, and if the name of the file is "X", skip it, else convert the slashes.

Very new to Windows batch scripting, can anyone help me out? I am writing a batch file for it, not using Powershell.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
@echo off

set TabbedPath=%C:\Users\Documents\Error;;=%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set content=

for /r %TabbedPath% %%g in (*.properties) do (
echo %%g
set content=!content! %%g

echo !content!

set "g=!content!"
set "g=!g:\=/!"
echo !g!

)
endlocal
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code and describe where you are stuck...

Comment: I have basiclaly tried to get the batch file to display all the files first so far.

Comment: Read [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php) and `set /?`. Visit http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: @aschipfl: I have edited the code to reflect what I have done so far.

Comment: There is a typo here ==> `set TabbedPath=%C:\Users\Documents\Error;;=%` should be ==> `set TabbedPath=%C:\Users\Documents\Error:;=%`

Comment: Are you wanting to process all *.properties files in all subdirectories as well?